# How to convert a template to JSON using JsonCPP

Tags: c++

I am trying to print JSON with [JSONCPP.lib](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/blob/master/example/streamWrite/streamWrite.cpp) but I am getting:

```
"Name" : "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"
```

```cpp
Json::Value coord(string& x)
{
    Json::Value result;
    result["Name"] = x;
    return result;
}

int i = 0;
std::vector<lstdTreeNode<std::string>> tree;
do {

    lstdTreeNode<std::string> tempTree(JGetContainerName(containerNew));

    if (containerNew.has_level_down() == true) {
        JDown(GetDown(containerNew), tempTree);
    }
    tree.push_back(tempTree);
    i ++ ;
} while (containerNew.next() != NULL);

void JDown(CONTAINER containerNew, lstdTreeNode<std::string> &con) {
    int i = 0;
    do {
        //std::cout << "\n      |       -->>  Down=======";
        if (containerNew.has_level_down() == true) {

            con.addChild(JGetContainerName(containerNew));
            JDown(GetDown(containerNew), con.getChildren(i));
        }
        else
        {
            con.addChild(JGetContainerName(containerNew));
        }
        i++;
    } while (containerNew.next() != NULL);
}

Json::Value root;
int j = 0; 
for each (auto rr in tree)
{
    Json::Value & coords = root["Containers"];
    coords[j] =coord( rr.getValue());
    Json::StreamWriterBuilder builder;
    const std::unique_ptr<Json::StreamWriter> writer(builder.newStreamWriter());
    writer->write(root, &std::cout);
    j++;
}
```

Template:

```cpp
template <typename T>
template < class T > class lstdTreeNode
{
public:
    lstdTreeNode()
    {
    }

    lstdTreeNode(const T& t)
    {
        this->t = t;
    }

    virtual ~lstdTreeNode()
    {

    }

    void addChild(const T& t)
    {
        this->children.push_back(lstdTreeNode(t));
    }

    // remove a child by value, note: if the node has multiple children with the same value, this will only delete the first child
    void removeChild(const T& t)
    {
        for (uint i = 0; i < this->children.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (this->children.at(i).t == t)
            {
                this->children.erase(this->children.begin() + i);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    void removeChildByIndex(const int index)
    {
        this->children.erase(this->children.begin() + index);
    }

    void setValue(const T& t)
    {
        this->t = t;
    }

    T& getValue()
    {
        return this->t;
    }

    const T& getValue() const
    {
        return this->t;
    }

    lstdTreeNode & getChildren(int i)
    {
        return this->children.at(i);
    }

    int & CCount()
    {
        return this->children.size();
    }

    std::vector< lstdTreeNode >& getChildren()
    {
        return this->children;
    }

    const std::vector< lstdTreeNode >& getChildren() const
    {
        return this->children;
    }

    // the type has to have an overloaded std::ostream << operator for print to work
    void print(const int depth = 0) const
    {
        
        std::cout << this->children.size() << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; ++i)
        {
            if (i != depth - 1) {
                std::cout << "    ";
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "|-- ";
            }
        }
        std::cout << this->t << std::endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < this->children.size(); ++i)
        {
            this->children.at(i).print(depth + 1);
        }
    }
    int count = 0;

private:
    T t;
    std::vector< lstdTreeNode > children;
};
```

Comment: `for each (auto rr in tree)` is not valid C++. Please show us a [mre] that we can test locally. You also have not mentioned which JSON library you're using or how your `tree` is constructed.

Comment: @Botje I have updated the question. The print function works as expected,  The print functions print in a hierarchy I want to do the same thing but in JSON format, to print to a file.

Comment: @Botje Do you know of a library on windows C++ that can easily serialise objects like .Net?

Comment: @Decoder94 asking for library recommendations is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for StackOverflow.

Comment: Please provide [mcve] use for example https://godbolt.org/z/nxP1Ed to reproduce issue so we could play with it. Based on description of problem and "solution", actual problem is not serializing, but invalid content of `tree` (there is a string which contains zero characters) or possible some undefined behavior.

Comment: Post the actual JSON from the serverside or wherever.

Answer (score -1):

Adding `.c_str()` fix the issue.

```
Json::Value coord(string& x)
{
    Json::Value result;
    result["Name"] = x.c_str();
    return result;
}
```

Before:

```
{
        "Containers" :
        [
                {
                        "Containers" :
                        [
                                {
                                        "Containers" :
                                        [
                                                {
                                                        "Containers" : null,
                                                        "Name" : "\u00071\u0725\ufffd⌂\u0000\u0000\u0005\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "Containers" : null,
                                                        "Name" : "\u00071\u0725\ufffd⌂\u0000\u0000\u0005\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"
                                                }
                                        ],
                                        "Name" : "H\u02dc$pH\u00c4@A^_^\u00cc"
                                }
                        ],
                        "Name" : "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"
                },
                {
                        "Containers" : null,
                        "Name" : "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000"
                }
        ]
}
```

After:

```
{
        "Containers" :
        [
                {
                        "Containers" :
                        [
                                {
                                        "Containers" :
                                        [
                                                {
                                                        "Containers" : null,
                                                        "Name" : "group"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "Containers" : null,
                                                        "Name" : "group"
                                                }
                                        ],
                                        "Name" : "group"
                                }
                        ],
                        "Name" : "L1_A"
                },
                {
                        "Containers" : null,
                        "Name" : "L1_b"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: This is not a proper solution, but hiding an actual problem. Actual problem is that `x` contains something invalid.

Comment: @MarekR Its the only solution I can find, am new to C++, invested hours and bounty but nothing.

Comment: Again you are searching for source of the problem in wrong place. Find reason why `x` contains sequence of terminating zeroes. This is clear indication that something else is broken. Your edit doesn't change/improve anything. You just sweep the problem under the rug.